# Extend an Angular Directive for a clock component to separately display datetime elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know how best to create an angular directive that encapsulates a clock component.

The component needs to have the time placed within a readonly input element with the day, week, month, year split between 2 span elements either side of the displayed time.

So far I've just got the clock outputing against 1 html element.

I've been building on the example in the Angular docs (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive "Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM") but have removed the dynamic formating option as it is not needed and also used momentjs to apply a static date formatting out of own preference.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular
    .module('labourRecordingApp')
    .directive('entryFormClock', ['$interval',
      function($interval) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {

          var stopTime;

          function updateTime() {

            var now = moment();
            var nowClockDate = moment(now).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");
            var nowClockTime = moment(now).format("HH:mm:ss");
            var nowClockWeek = "Week " + moment(now).format("W.E");

            element.text(nowClockDate + " " + nowClockTime + " " + nowClockWeek);
          }

          stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 1000);

          element.on('$destroy', function() {
            $interval.cancel(stopTime);
          });
        }
      }
    ]);
}());
```

```html
<span entry-form-clock></span>
```

So I'm needing some markup as follows but then am unsure of the Angular side.

```html
<span>day month</span>
<input type="text" readonly="true" value="timeonly" />
<span>year week.day</span>
```

I'm imagining this is best implemented in a template html but need some how-to assistance.

Aside - this SPA is going to operate for days and weeks on end and the browser will be in kiosk mode for a manufacturing shop floor application. My only point here is the day, month, year need to be dynamic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app
.directive('entryFormClock', ['$interval',
  function($interval) {
    return {
      template: '<div>{{yymmdd}}<input type="text" value="{{min}}"></div>',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element) {
        var stopTime;

      function updateTime() {

        var d = new Date();

        scope.yymmdd = [d.getMonth()+1,
           d.getDate(),
           d.getFullYear()].join('/');
        scope.min = [d.getHours(),
           d.getMinutes(),
           d.getSeconds()].join(':');
      }

      stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 1000);

      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(stopTime);
      });

      }
    };
  }
]);
```

It shows two separate child, Update your code accordingly.

Comment: I've not tested the specific date manipulation but the template aspect is working for me and have marked as answer on that basis - cheers.